# c#. Обеспечить доступ к private методу только для другого класса

Tags: c#, c++, шаблоны-проектирования

Изучаю паттерн Медиатор на примере консольной имитации форм.

Имеется 3 класса - `Button`, `TextField`, `Form` (медиатор).

Button имеет флаг `isEnabled` и сеттер/геттер. `TextField` имеет строку `input` и сеттер/геттер.

Медиатор имеет ссылки на экземпляры `Button` и `TextField` и метод, который устанавливает флаг кнопки в зависимости от того, пуст или нет `input` у `TextField`. Проблема заключается в том, что сеттер флага публичный и может быть вызван не только из медиатора, но и из другого любого места программы, что может нарушить логику. Если сделать сеттер приватным, тогда я не смогу изменить флаг, используя проверяющий метод медиатора.

Вопрос - есть ли какой-то способ сделать сеттер кнопки доступным только медиатора/определенного метода медиатора или хотя бы для любого класса, который содержит в себе ссылку на кнопку (но не наследует её), при этом не доступным нигде больше?

В С++ для подобных целей вроде бы можно было использовать `friendly`

Comment: Почитайте https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204739/what-is-the-c-sharp-equivalent-of-friend
Выберите что-то подходящее.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В .NET подобной единицей изоляции является *сборка*. Если вы хотите, чтобы какое-то свойство было доступно только для доверенных классов, используйте `internal`, и помещайте ваши доверенные классы в эту сборку. Считается, что над данной сборкой у вас есть контроль, а над посторонними может и не быть.

Comment: а еще, вложенные классы имеют доступ к приватным полям контейнера

Comment: @Grundy: Ну это да, но вроде для случая ТС не подходит?

Comment: @Grundy, жаль что два класса не могут быть вложены друг в друга.